# Система диалогов на PHP

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Решил добавить на сайт систему диалогов, самую элементарную.
Но не понимаю логику, еще не дорос, чтобы самому все осознать, а инфы не так уж и много, если сравнить с инструкцией по созданию формы регистрации.
Кто-нибудь может расписать логику этой системы, желательно с командами `MySQL`?

Нужно отталкиваться от того, что есть 2 таблицы:
`users` - с уникальными `id`,
`messages` с `from_id` и `to_id`.

Нужно чтобы пользователи могли друг другу отправлять сообщения и чтобы никто не видел эти сообщения, кроме их самих.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если совсем простой алгоритм:

1. создаете скрипт `send.php`, который принимает 2 параметра: `to_id` и `message`, а так-же из сессии берет параметр `user_id`, который будет у нас играть роль `from_id`.

   В таблице Messages нужно создать 5 полей: `id` (автоинкремент), `from_id`, `to_id`, `message`, `timestamp` (по умолчанию в `timestamp` поставить текущее время)

   далее в скрипте выполняем подобную команду:

   `INSERT INTO Messages (from_id, to_id, message) VALUES ($_SESSION['user_id']), $_POST['to_id'], $_POST['message'])` - здесь если правильно создана таблица, поля id и timestamp заполняться автоматически
2. Создаете скрипт messages.php, который получает GET параметр from_id. Скрипт будет выводить все сообщения от заданного юзера

   в нем получаете все сообщения для юзера из сессии (т.е. текущего юзера в браузере):

   `SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE from_id IN ($_GET['from_id'], $_SESSION['user_id']) AND to_id IN ($_GET['from_id'], $_SESSION['user_id']) ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 1000`

   И выводите сообщения на форму.
3. На главной странице index.php, вы размещаете ссылки на пользователей, которые писали юзеру.

   Получить юзеров, которые писали текущему, можно таким запросом:

   `SELECT DISTINCT from_id FROM Messages WHERE to_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 1000`

   И далее в цикле выводим ссылки на messages.php?from_id=$from_id

P.S. Это очень сильно упрощенная схема. Здесь я опустил вопрос sql инъекций и прочие проверки, так напрямую из POST и GET лучше ничего не использовать. Так-же здесь нет пагинации. Кроме этого систему сообщений конечно лучше же делать асинхроно, реализуя api для отправки и получения сообщений

Comment: По описанной схеме юзер будет видеть адресованные ему сообщения, но не будет видеть своих сообщений.

Comment: Во первых, огромное спасибо! Но все же кое что недопонял. А именно - как сделать так, чтобы при клике на юзера открывалась переписка именно с ним? Не через цикл же, и при этом чтобы не нужно было использовать ларавел

Comment: @AlexSvetlov У Вас страничка должна быть с юзерами. которая ведет на messages.php?from_id=100, добавлю сейчас в ответ, и еще исправлю то что выше мне написали

Comment: `Здесь я опустил вопрос sql инъекций` - очень зря. Одна команда `addslashes` для SQL запросов (или даже лучше подготовленные выражения) и `htmlspecialchars` для экранирования вывода сообщений решают вопрос безопасности. Проще написать, чем отсылать в маны.

Answer (score 0):

Структура таблицы (минимально)

```
CREATE TABLE message ( ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                       sender_id INT,
                       receiver_id INT,
                       message TEXT,
                       created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                       CONSTRAINT fk_sender_id 
                           FOREIGN KEY (sender_id)
                           REFERENCES user (user_id)
                           ON UPDATE CASCADE
                           ON DELETE RESTRICT,
                       CONSTRAINT fk_receiver_id 
                           FOREIGN KEY (receiver_id)
                           REFERENCES user (user_id)
                           ON UPDATE CASCADE
                           ON DELETE RESTRICT );
```

Запрос на получение диалога текущего пользователя (`@current_user_id`) и его текущего собеседника (`@opponent_id`)

```
SELECT sender_id, receiver_id, message, created_at
FROM message
WHERE @current_user_id IN (sender_id, receiver_id)
  AND @opponent_id IN (sender_id, receiver_id)
ORDER BY created_at [ASC | DESC]
```